# Start Android emulator from command line and dismiss cmd window

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, command-prompt

I'm trying to start the Android emulator from commandline using

```
start "" emulator.exe @Nexus_5X_API_24
```

But this spawns another cmd window.

Is there a way to start the emulator from command line without having a dangling cmd window that you can't close?